Fantasy novel where a brother and sister go to a fantasy and travel with a one-armed warrior
I don't remember much about this, but as far as I remember the book (it might have been an audio book) was about a sister and a brother that ended up in a fantasy world.
The part I remember the most is a one armed swordsman/warrior that traveled with them. My brain tells me his name was something along the lines of "Errol", but I'm not sure. I think he lost his arm in some kind of spell to protect something and might have gotten it back after removing the protection.

In roughly which year did you read (or listen to) this?

A one-armed warrior named "Er'ril" features in Wit'ch War (2000) by James Clemens.
Quoting the book's blurb from Goodreads:

In her hands, the young wit'ch Elena holds the awesome energies of blood magick--and more. For the fate of all Alasea hinges on her recovery of the Blood Diary, a potent talisman forged five hundred years ago, then locked away behind wards too strong for any mage to break. But only with the secrets recorded in its pages can Elena defeat the evil magicks of the Dark Lord. The challenge? The Diary lies hidden in A'loa Glen, the fabled city that belongs to Shorkan, chief lieutenant of the Dark Lord, and his fearsome army.
Now, with the aid of the ocean-dwelling Sy-wen and her great dragon, Elena prepares a desperate invasion of A'loa Glen. At her side stands the one-armed warrior Er'ril, her faithful protector and the only man who knows how to unlock the wards surrounding the Blood Diary--a man who also happens to be the brother of the dreaded Shorkan.
Meanwhile, Elena's brother, whose magick brings him prophetic dreams, has glimpsed a future in which Elena falls by the deadly sword of . . . Er'ril. But his visions do not always come true. How can he act against his sister's trusted guardian on the basis of a future betrayal that may never happen? For Elena's sake, and for the sake of all Alasea, how can he afford not to?


Witch Fire is the first book in the series and Erril is initially introduced as a juggler if that helps jog any bells

@Jontia Except for the entire first few chapters where Er'ril is whole, and at home, and loses his brother... :)

Eep. Totally forgot the prologue.

This also bears some resemblance to parts of Stephen King's The Dark Tower series. The events are spread out over the series, so unless you were listening for quite some time, it may not be the one you are after. The books are loosely based off the King Arthur tales, and are set in a formerly high-technology fantasy world in declines so now has American Old-West technology and features - gun fights, horse-and-carriage sort of things, as well as relics of more advanced technology.
In this series, the main character Roland (point of difference) is a "Gunslinger", which is basically a knight but uses revolvers (because gunslingers are based on cowboy movie characters) instead of swords. At some point in the series (Volume II, The Drawing of the Three), Roland loses part of his hand when attacked by "lobstrosities", the loss of his hand means that he is no longer as effective at gunfighting as formerly.
Roland is collecting his "Ka-tet", which is a group of people bound by fate and treated like blood-siblings. In this case the Ka-tet consists of Roland, a child named Jake, and Eddie and Susannah Dean (get married in the books). They aren't siblings at all in real-life, just tightly tied by fate and destiny.
